# firebase login google email

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I am building a website as a school project and I am using Angularjs with Firebase.

I am trying to check if a user id is located in an array but it doesn't seem to be able to compare strings properly.

The controller:

```
'use strict';

var AboutController = angular.module('AboutController', []);

AboutController.factory('Auth', ['$firebaseAuth', function($firebaseAuth) {
  var ref = new Firebase('https://MYURL.firebaseio.com/');
  return $firebaseAuth(ref);
}]);

AboutController.controller('AboutCtrl', function ($scope, $firebase, Auth) {

  var usrRef = new Firebase('https://MYURL.firebaseio.com/Users');
  $scope.users = $firebase(usrRef).$asArray();

  $scope.auth = Auth;
  $scope.account = $scope.auth.$getAuth();
  var id = $scope.account.google.id;
  var check = false;
  for(var user in $scope.users){
    if(user.UID === id){
      check = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  $scope.isUser = check;
  if($scope.isUser !== true){
    $scope.users.$add({
      UID: $scope.account.google.id,
    });
  }
});
```

The html page:

```
<div ng-controller="AboutCtrl">
  <div>
    <h3>User Data</h3>
    <p>{{account.google.id}}</p>
    <pre>{{account|json}}</pre>
    <p>User has logged in before:{{isUser}}</p>
    <pre>{{users|json}}</pre>
    <div>
      <p>This compares the current UID's in the db to the current user's uid</p>
      <div ng-repeat='usr in users'>
        <p>{{usr.UID}} {{usr.UID == account.google.id}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see the html page does the same comparison as the controller but the html page returns the correct answer whereas the controller does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$scope.account is null when you're not authenticated. It might be better using $onAuth here.

> $onAuth(); Listens for changes to the client’s authentication state. The provided callback will fire when the client’s authenticate state changes. [Source](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-user-authentication-and-management-onauthcallback-context)

$scope.users = $firebase(usrRef).$asArray() is asynchronous. When you loop over $scope.user this might be empty at that time. You should wait till the data has been received from Firebase. Check out $loaded();

> $loaded(); Returns a promise which is resolved when the initial array data has been downloaded from Firebase. The promise resolves to the array itself. [Source](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-loaded)

Comment: Thank you. That was apart of the issue. The other problem was that 'user.UID' was returning as undefined.